# Django не видит статику fontawesome на продакшене

Tags: python, django, static

На продакшене получаю вот такую историю, на локалке все ок:

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://my_address/static/fontawesomefree/css/all.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Пробовал collectstatic, не помогает

base.html

```
<link href="{% static 'fontawesomefree/css/all.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_collections')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR, ]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: На продакшене раздачей статики должен заниматься не Django, а стоящий перед ним веб-сервер, настроенный на раздачу файлов из папки STATIC_ROOT

Comment: Спс, все ок, решил